# Remember userMedia selection when user select first time

Tags: javascript

Currently i am working on audio and video call application. In this application Whenever user click on audio or Video call button, The browser pop up a dilog and ask for user media selection every time.

My requirement is whenever user select user media first time after that the userMedia selection pop up donot came again and again.

Please i am using javascript webRTC Api. Please help me.

Comment: start here: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your site on https. In chrome, that will remember the permission. In Firefox, it will allow the user to remember the permission.

Also note that getUserMedia will stop working on plain, unencrypted http in Chrome soon.